# UITableView поверх UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, xcode, ios7, прокрутка

Доброе время суток, возникла такая проблема, у меня есть скролл вью, на пол экрана на нём расположены кнопки/лейблы, другая половина экрана занимает таблица, хочу сделать так, что бы при перемотке таблицы скролилась вся вьюха, уже 2-й день с этим автолояутом играюсь, никак допереть не могу :(
Люди добрые, помогите пожалуйста, буду прям очень благодаре

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется, что самый легкий и быстрый способ решать такие задачи (по крайне мере я делаю именно так) такой:

Кидаете таблицу на весь экран, перед ячейкой вставьляете вьюху - на которой у вас кнопки/лейблы и т.д. И всё замечательно работает и на 3.5 и на 4 дюймовых апаратах, вот рисунок как пример:

[image]

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое, я промчался несколько дней подряд со всякими функциями и прочими вещами, а тут оказалось всё на столько легко и не замудрённо, аааа капец, я не верю своим глазам что всё работает без всяких функцияя/автолояутов и прочей лабуды!!!
Спасибо Вам, Вы меня прям так выручили!

Comment: Спасибо!А я мучался!

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте *все* вынести в таблицу. То что сейчас у вас в скроллвью, просто отправьте в отдельную ячейку или футер/хэдэр и не морочьте голову с синхронизацией этих двух контролов.

Comment: Такой вариант не подойдёт, так как на странице очень много элементов присутствует (

Comment: И что? Почему этот вариант не подойдет? Это практически идеальный вариант если у вас дофига данных на экране. Бейте вашу вьюху на куски и отрисовывайте "построчно".

Comment: Извините за глупый вопрос, то есть, нужно создать скажем две ячейки, в 1-й карта/лейблы/кнопки а во второй уже данные, который я в данный момент вывожу в таблицу?

Comment: Да, как вариант, вероятно будет много кода, но должно работать хорошо и красиво, заодно будет решена проблема с iPhone 3.5"/4".

P.S. я вообще чуть ли не на каждый кусочек экрана создаю xib+cell, писанины много, но поддержка и изменения вообще бескровные.

Comment: Вот ещё такой вопрос, у меня таблица кастомная, возможно будет сделать одну таблицу со всеми элементами страницы, а пол таблицы кастомные?

Comment: Вынесите часть своей вьюхи, к примеру, в хэдэр секции, остальная часть таблицы - ячейки - будет такая же как у вас сейчас.

Comment: Ребята, и Вам большоее спасибо за помощь!
Как хорошо что мир не без добрых людей!!!

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно вас понял, то

Реализуем метод UIScrollViewDelegate В своем UIViewController
когда мы становимся делегатом UITableViewDelegate, мы автоматом делегируем и ее scroll поводение, т. к. это сабкласс скролла, итак в методах:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
if (scrollView == self.tableView) { // проверка на тот случай, если вы делегируете еще и свой вторй UIScrollView
self.mySecondScrollView.contentOffset = self.tableView.contentOffset; // или расчитываем значения если зависимость contentOffset'ов не прямая
}
}
```

Comment: Всё работает :)
Только есть маленький косяк, получается что таблица уезжает со всем вьюхай, как это можно поправить?(

У меня такая иерархия:

Главная вью
-----скролл вью
----------вью (а на ней уже и таблица и все кнопки/лейблы...)

Comment: совершенно точно не стоит класть таблицу на скролл вью, если можете, сделайте view - (table и scroll рядом) в принципе не очень понятно что именно вы пытаетесь там запрогать такое, поэтому помогать тут немного сложно

Comment: @iFreeman, смотрите, у меня сверху идёт карта (mapView) после неё идёт ряд лейблом, кнопок, после идёт сама таблица, и нужно скролить все элементы на вьюхе

размещено всё так:
View -> ScrollView -> ContentView (Labels, Buttons, UITableView)

Answer (score 0):

Для тех, кто по хардкору и решил не делать хэдэр у таблицы - вот код, для рассчитывания высоты скролл вью:

```
(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
[super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

CGSize maximumTableSize = CGSizeMake(self.yourTableView.frame.size.width, FLT_MAX);
CGSize expectedTableSize = [self.yourTableView sizeThatFits: maximumTableSize];

//назначаем фрейм с нужной высотой
previousFrame = self.yourTableView.frame;
newFrame = self.yourTableView.frame;
newFrame.size.height = expectedTableSize.height;
self.yourTableView.frame = newFrame;

//назначаем высоту заднего скролла
[self.yourScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.yourScrollView.contentSize.width, self.yourScrollView.contentSize.height - previousFrame.size.height + self.yourTableView.frame.size.height )];
}
```